# what can affect nhibernate bulk insert performance?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have various large data modification operations in a project built on c# and Fluent NHibernate.
The DB is sqlite (on disk rather than in memory as I'm interested in performance)

I wanted to check performance of these so I created some tests to feed in large amounts of data and let the processes do their thing. The results from 2 of these processes have got me pretty confused.

The first is a fairly simple case of taking data supplied in an XML file doing some light processing and importing it. The XML contains around 172,000 rows and the process takes a total of around 60 seconds to run with the actual inserts taking around 40 seconds.

In the next process, I do some processing on the same set of data. So I have a DB with approx 172,000 rows in one table. The process then works through this data, doing some heavier processing and generating a whole bunch of DB updates (inserts and updates to the same table).
In total, this results in around 50,000 rows inserted and 80,000 updated.
In this case, the processing takes around 30 seconds, which is fine, but saving the changes to the DB takes over 30 mins! and it crashes before it finishes with an sqlite 'disk or i/o error'

So the question is: why are the inserts/updates in the second process so much slower? They are working on the same table of the same database with the same connection. In both cases, IStatelessSession is used and ado.batch_size is set to 1000.

In both cases, the code looks that does the update like this:

```
BulkDataInsert((IStatelessSession session) =>
{
    foreach (Transaction t in transToInsert) { session.Insert(t); }
    foreach (Transaction t in transToUpdate) { session.Update(t); }
});
```

(although the first process has no 'transToUpdate' line as it's only inserts - Removing the update line and just doing the inserts still takes almost 10 minutes.)
The transTo* variables are List with the objects to be updated/inserted.

BulkDataInsert creates the session and handles the DB transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to my test setup.
As is pretty common with nhibernate based projects, I had been using in-memory sqlite databases for unit testing. These work great but one downside is that if you close the session, it destroys the database.
Consequently, my unit of work implementation contains a 'PreserveSession' property to keep the session alive and just create new transactions when needed.

My new performance tests are using on-disk databases but they still use the common code for setting up test databases and so have PreserveSession set to true.

It seems that having several sessions all left open (even though they're not doing anything) starts to cause problems after a while including the performance drop off and the disk IO error.

I re-ran the second test with PreserveSession set to false and immediately I'm down from over 30 minutes to under 2 minutes. Which is more where I'd expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your second process. However, here are some things to consider:

1. Are there any clustered or non-clustered indexes on the table?
2. How many disk drives do you have?
3. How many threads are writing to the DB in the second test?

It seems that you are experiencing IO bottlenecks that can be resolved by having more disks, more threads, indexes, etc.

So, assuming a lot of things, here is what I "think" is happening:

1. In the first test your table probably has no indexes, and since you are just inserting data, it is a sequential insert in a single thread which can be pretty fast - especially if you are writing to one disk.
2. Now, in the second test, you are reading data and then updating data. Your SQL instance has to find the record that it needs to update. If you do not have any indexes this "find" action is basically a table scan, which will happen for each one of those 80,000 row updates. This will make your application really really slow.

The simplest thing you could probably do is add a clustered index on the table for a unique key, and the best option is to use the columns that you are using in the where clause to "update" those rows.

Hope this helps.

DISCLAIMER: I made quite a few assumptions

Comment: 1. There are 2 indicies. The primary key (long, or int as this is SQLite and it treats them the same) and another non-clustered on a date column. 2. Just the one drive. SQLite is a single file based DB. 3. Just the one thread.     It's the same table in the first and second tests. I also get the same slow down if I only save the inserts and just ignore the updates so I don't think it's anything to do with the table itself. The updates will all be by ID and this is the primary key and clustered index so should be about as fast as you can get.